# locking a specific record in MySQL

Tags: mysql, locking, nonblocking

I am about to implement a record locking mechanism as follows:

```
Table1:
    Field: "ID" (AutoIncrement, Primary)
    Field: "Name" (Text)
    Field: "More fields..."

Table2:
    Field: "ID" (Unique)
```

In order to lock a specific record in Table1, I'll create a record in Table2 with the same ID. If this creation fails due to such a record already existing, then the record must be locked by another process and I spin. If it succeeds, I have the lock and can modify the record. When I'm done, I delete the lock record in Table2.

My question is whether this is a valid way to implement a per-record lock, and if not, is there such a thing?

Cheers,
Charlie.

Comment: the clever people at MySQL have already done this for you - it's called the innodb transactional engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [innodb](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-lock-modes.html) for row-based locking,
or even [read-lock](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) instead of impose locking to another table,
(rather to let mysql to handle race-condition)